# How do I extract a zip file using javascript?

Tags: javascript, parsing, zip

How do I parse zip file string. I looked for hours I couldn't find an easy to do it. All the examples I found didn't make much sense.

Comment: Is.. this really hardly possible? Kind of interesting.

Comment: You'll have to use something that can represent binary data, like a blob/file/typed array not a string

Answer (score 3):

I use [zipjs](http://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/) to handle zip files. A simple library that can handle reading and writing zip files.

Answer (score -1):

BE MORE CLEAR NEXT TIME. I think this answer is what you need to hear.

A zip file can not be parsed with simple JavaScript. There is simply no native function that can ope ZIP files. There are certain libraries out there, but personally i have not found one that worked properly, and most use some kind of flash plugin to make it "work".

If you really want a zip file to be presented in Javascript, you will have to build its function with PHP. PHP can write to zip files, and read them: [PHP ZIP](http://php.net/zip). If you want to read the contents of a zip file, you would have to upload the file to the server (can be done with JS), then make the PHP return a JSON object with all the file_info of all the files inside the ZIP. And last but not least, JS should be able to acces another PHP page that retrieves a particular file, which can be done by reading the file and setting a `mimetype` before outputting its contents.

Comment: Downvoted because outdated. Modern JavaScript/Node seem to work pretty well, also PHP is not really required.